# Не работает функция для двухсвязного списка

Tags: c

Задача такова: нужно произвести дублирование элементов, поле информации которых - чётное число , проблема заключается в том ,что в оператор if не игнорируется т.е. условие точно написано правильно , но почему-то сами манипуляции с новым элементом не работают не понимаю почему.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct TNode
{
    int data;
    struct TNode *next;
    struct TNode *prev;
};
typedef struct TNode Node;
void CreateNode(Node** head, Node** tail, int data)
{
    Node *NewNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
    NewNode->data = data; 
    if ((*head) == NULL) 
    {
        NewNode->next = NULL;
        NewNode->prev = NULL;
        (*tail) = NewNode;
        (*head) = NewNode;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        NewNode->next = NULL;
        (*tail)->next = NewNode;
        NewNode->prev = (*tail);
        (*tail) = NewNode;
    }
}
void copy(Node** head,Node**tail)
{
    Node *tmp;
    tmp = (*head);
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if ((tmp->data % 2) == 0)
        {
            Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            P1->data = tmp->data;
            P1->prev = tmp->prev;
            tmp->prev = P1;
            P1->next = tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        CreateNode(&head,&tail, i + 2);
    }
    copy(&head, &tail);
    if (head == NULL)//0 elements
        {
        printf("The list is empty!");
        }
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    getchar();
    return 1;
}```
````

Comment: В функции copy(), внутри if-а поле next у элемента, предшествующего tmp (а для первого в списке указатель head) надо тоже модифицировать, чтобы он на P1 ссылался.

Comment: Вставка копии элемента перед tmp, как @avp верно указал, реализована некорректно. Возможно проще вставлять копию после tmp?

Comment: У вас же есть функция для создания ноды есть, зачем вы дублируете код в функции копирования?

Comment: @Serge3leo,Условие задачи не позволяет : нужно именно перед элементом дублировать .

Comment: @こきん,возможно не правильно понял ваш вопрос , у меня такое условие задачи просто .

Answer (score 0):

```
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    if ((tmp->data % 2) == 0)
    {
        Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        P1->data = tmp->data;
        tmp->prev->next = P1;
        P1->prev = tmp->prev;
        P1->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = P1;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

Comment: @apv, как вы и сказали я модифицировал предшествующий tmp-у элемент чтобы он на P1 ссылался , оно тоже не работает.Может ,мне нужно сдвигать tmp на 1 элемент назад и уже пробовать как с односвязным ? Но тогда пропадает смысл функционала двухсвязного списка не так ли?

Comment: Хм, странно, что “tmp->prev->next = P1;” не падает для первого элемента списка, который у Вас должен содержать tmp->data == 2 и tmp->prev == 0.

Answer (score 0):

При вставке дубля перед элементом с четным `data`, надо не забывать корректировать `head`, если копируете первый элемент списка.

```
void copy(Node** head)
{
  Node *tmp;

  tmp = (*head);
  while (tmp != NULL)
    {
      if ((tmp->data)%2==0) {
        Node *P1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        P1->data = tmp->data;
        P1->next = tmp;
        if (P1->prev = tmp->prev) 
          P1->prev->next = P1;
        else  // copy first list element
          *head = P1;
        tmp->prev = P1;
      }
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что для такой реализации параметр `tail` в функции не нужен.

Comment: `if (P1->prev = tmp->prev)` А как компилятор заходит в это условие если , выше в коде не было описано данного действия, я этого не понимаю. И когда вы написали `P1->next = tmp;` связь с элементами до tmp не теряется? Неужели , к одной структуре могут быть "привязаны" одновременно две структуры? И еще: мой код был не верным потому-что я не описывал поведение , когда есть только 1 элемент или я что-то упустил?

Comment: `if (P1->prev = tmp->prev)` -- это сразу 2 действия, инициализация P1->prev и проверка, нулем или нет. Если не нулем, то существует  пердыдущий элемент, который ссылается на tmp и этот указатель (next в предыдущем элементе) надо скорректировать, чтобы он указавал на P1, а если 0, то дублируем первый элемент и тогда надо корректировать голову списка. // *`"...когда вы написали P1->next = tmp; связь с элементами до tmp не теряется?"`* -- каким образом? P1 совсем новый элемент. Тут только начинается его инициализация и на другие элементы ссылается пока еще только tmp.

Comment: В своем коде вы упустили корректировку головы списка, когда tmp первый

Comment: *`"Неужели , к одной структуре могут быть "привязаны" одновременно две структуры?"`* -- ничто не мешает нескольким разным указателям указывать на одну и ту же память. В указателях нет никакой магии. Это просто числа в памяти. Их значения интерпретируются как адреса (ссылки) на память. Или я не понял вопроса?

Comment: спасибо я все понял :)